# must have same datatype, got tf.uint8 != tf.float32 (behavioral cloning simulator)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

While trying the project of [car behavioral cloning](https://github.com/naokishibuya/car-behavioral-cloning), I successfully trained my model and generated the file model-001.h5.
now in order to test the model, it must successfully drive the vehicle in Udacity self-driving simulator this is done by running the drive.py and the generated model-001.h5 file

```
python drive.py model-001.h5
```

however, I receive this error.

```
x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.uint8 != tf.float32 
x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.uint8 != tf.float32 
x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.uint8 != tf.float32
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF1qz.png)

I don't know if this is error is from drive.py or model.py or utils.py
but here is the drive.py code here:

```
import argparse
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import os
import shutil

import numpy as np
import socketio
import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask
from io import BytesIO

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

import utils

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)
model = None
prev_image_array = None

MAX_SPEED = 25.0
MIN_SPEED = 10.0

speed_limit = MAX_SPEED

@sio.on('telemetry')
def telemetry(sid, data):
    if data:
        # The current steering angle of the car
        steering_angle = float(data["steering_angle"])
        # The current throttle of the car
        throttle = float(data["throttle"])
        # The current speed of the car
        speed = float(data["speed"])
        # The current image from the center camera of the car
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data["image"])))
        # save frame
        if args.image_folder != '':
            timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f')[:-3]
            image_filename = os.path.join(args.image_folder, timestamp)
            image.save('{}.jpg'.format(image_filename))
            
        try:
            image = np.asarray(image)       # from PIL image to numpy array
            image = utils.preprocess(image) # apply the preprocessing
            image = np.array([image])       # the model expects 4D array

            # predict the steering angle for the image
            steering_angle = float(model.predict(image, batch_size=1))
            # lower the throttle as the speed increases
            # if the speed is above the current speed limit, we are on a downhill.
            # make sure we slow down first and then go back to the original max speed.
            global speed_limit
            if speed > speed_limit:
                speed_limit = MIN_SPEED  # slow down
            else:
                speed_limit = MAX_SPEED
            throttle = 1.0 - steering_angle**2 - (speed/speed_limit)**2

            print('{} {} {}'.format(steering_angle, throttle, speed))
            send_control(steering_angle, throttle)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        
    else:
        # NOTE: DON'T EDIT THIS.
        sio.emit('manual', data={}, skip_sid=True)


@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid)
    send_control(0, 0)


def send_control(steering_angle, throttle):
    sio.emit(
        "steer",
        data={
            'steering_angle': steering_angle.__str__(),
            'throttle': throttle.__str__()
        },
        skip_sid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Remote Driving')
    parser.add_argument(
        'model',
        type=str,
        help='Path to model h5 file. Model should be on the same path.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'image_folder',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        default='',
        help='Path to image folder. This is where the images from the run will be saved.'
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    model = load_model(args.model)

    if args.image_folder != '':
        print("Creating image folder at {}".format(args.image_folder))
        if not os.path.exists(args.image_folder):
            os.makedirs(args.image_folder)
        else:
            shutil.rmtree(args.image_folder)
            os.makedirs(args.image_folder)
        print("RECORDING THIS RUN ...")
    else:
        print("NOT RECORDING THIS RUN ...")

    # wrap Flask application with engineio's middleware
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

    # deploy as an eventlet WSGI server
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 4567)), app)
```

even though the telemetry(sid, data) has an if statement to change the incoming data to float format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be helpful to see on what line you get an error.

It's not obvious to me where the "if statement to change the incoming data to float format" that you refer to is. I see that the model is called on whatever image is loaded, in whatever datatype it comes from. I predict that the image is stored as uint8, the most efficient storage for a (0,255) colour representation.

So try:

`image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32)`

To create an array of the correct datatype for your model, which I am presuming is tf.float32.